# Как сделать/забиндить CheckEdit?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, devexpress

Я хочу сделать `CheckEdit`, который бы мне задавал у других `CheckEdit` выбрано, то есть `IsChecked=true`.

Ниже приведен пример генерации `CheckEdit`

XAML

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="{Binding FilePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Padding="2.5" Margin="3"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

А вот я задаю свою кнопку которая выделяет все CheckEdit

```
<Button x:Name="filtrButton" Content="Filtr" Command="{Binding FiltrCommand}"  Padding="5" Margin="3" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
<dxe:CheckEdit Content="Select All" Padding="2.5" Margin="3"  IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Можно ли как-то связать в XAML?

Comment: Если узнаешь ответ, то скажи

Comment: я сделал через проперти  данные выводяться хорошо но СheckEdit  не работает, тоесть не показывает выбраные СheckEdit private bool? _allSelected= false;
        public bool? AllSelected
        {
            get { return _allSelected; }
            set
            {
                _allSelected = value;

                foreach (var item in TempList)
                {
                    item.IsChecked = _allSelected;
                }
                MyProperty = TempList;
                OnPropertyChange("AllSelected");
            }
        } это только пол пути

Comment: Может всё-же попробуете стандартный CheckBox?

Answer (score 1):

Уточните вашу разметку, а то пока что два несвязанных куска кода. Кроме того, в одном месте биндится на `Checked`, а в другом на `IsChecked`.

По большому счёту, вам нужно при нажатии на мастер-чекбокс менять значение свойства у всех элементов в коллекции, к которой привязан `ItemsControl`. 
Не забудьте использовать `ObservableCollection` для привязки, иначе UI не узнает о изменениях